# Redirect user after node add/edit

Tags: 7, redirection

I want to redirect users to a custom page, after they create a node or edit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add a custom submit handler where you can set the redirection path.

See the [FAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7) for more details about form redirection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! i've read about the FAPI but a still have question to go ahead : Where should i put the hook_form_alter function ?

Comment: @ousneo In drupal 7 you can put it in your theme or in a custom module you create.

Comment: thanks ! i have donne it with your help! by using theme file

Comment: please see @Dmitry Vyal answer

Comment: In Drupal 7 you can add an additional submit handler with: $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_handler';

Comment: Here's a module that does a redirect after saving. https://drupal.org/project/node_save_redirect

Comment: While accepted, this answer is too brief to be useful. It really matters *how* you add your custom submit handler, and this answer is silent on that. Best answer IMHO is that from @leymannx (but see by comment about the edit use case).

Answer (score 4):

You can create a rule that redirects the user to any page when they create or edit a specific content type. When you add a rule select "After Creating New Content" add also a condition of "Content Has Type". You Do section will give you the option to redirect a user to any page you want.

For a redirect after editing a node, just create a new rule and select "After updating Existing Content" as your first option.

Comment: I used Rules to redirect after creating a specific content, but the user gets no feedback now. I want to show the user that "Your content is created". How can I improve this ?

Comment: Add another action after the redirect action to "Show a configurable message on the site" and add your custom message from there.

Comment: I added another Rule but i think I miss something in my custom theme because the message is not shown on my frontpage. I'm using a module 'Better messages' to show these kind of messages in a popup ![rule config](http://i46.tinypic.com/1kh09.png)

Comment: My experience is that overlay breaks Rules redirecting, beware.

Comment: In my case this the node add form was embedded insider a panel. hook_form_alter didn't catch it. But rules worked great!

Answer (score 3):

When doing this, ensure to also unset a possible existing destination which normally is added to the URL when you click the edit button to edit an existing node.

Replace `article` in `MYMODULE_form_article_node_form_alter` with your content type's machine name.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_article_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_MYMODULE_node_form_redirect';
}

/**
 * Submit callback.
 */
function _MYMODULE_node_form_redirect($form, &$form_state) {

  // Unset destination first.
  unset($_GET['destination']);
  unset($_REQUEST['edit']['destination']);

  $form_state['redirect'] = 'FOO/BAR';
}
```

Comment: This works for redirects after *adding* a node, but not after editing it.  I understand that the calls to `unset` the `destination` is supposed to handle the edit use case, but they have no effect on my Drupal 7 site.

Comment: @FreeRadical – You are right. I updated the answer to use [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) instead, which targets both – add and edit.

Comment: @FreeRadical – Additional info: [Difference between create new and edit node in form alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34259/difference-between-create-new-and-edit-node-in-form-alter).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not very clear on it, but you should modify `$_GET['destination']` variable, not `$_REQUEST` or `$form_state['redirect']`.

Comment: Modifying $form_state['redirect'] works fine in Drupal 7...

Answer (score 1):

in Drupal 7 you can alter the node edit form to 'attach' your own submit function, in which you can alter form_state of the node delete confirmation form to include the 'destination' parameter... just did this in a custom theme i've been developing as a subtheme of the 'seven' admin theme...

Documentation for [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

You can add this hook to a template/theme, not just to modules.

so in your theme's `template.php`, add this form alter hook:

```
function yourtheme_node_delete_form_submit( &$form, &$form_state ) {
    $form_state[ 'redirect' ][ 1 ][ 'query' ][ 'destination' ] = "admin/content";
}
```

and then, voila. no longer redirected to homepage after a node is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from here [http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#comment-18139](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#comment-18139)

```
<?php
  function FORM_NAME_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = array(
      // $path
      'path/to/redirect/to',
      // $options
      array('query' => array('key' => 'value')),
      // $http_response_code
      302,
    );
  }  
?>
```