# Redirect to a custom page after a node has been added or edited

Tags: 7, forms, redirection

Using `hook_form_alter`, how can I redirect a user to a a custom page after creating or editing a node instead of the  node that was created or edited?

The current code for `hook_form_alter()` is the following one:

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'custom-node-form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Add Entry');
    $form['field_custom_email']['und'][0]['value']['#element_validate'] = array('_custom_form_validate_email');
  }
}
```

Comment: "There is a module for that" : Node Destination (https://www.drupal.org/project/node_destination) but it is only available for D6. Maybe can it be adapted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function custom_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#node']->type == 'custom') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Add Entry');
    $form['field_custom_email']['und'][0]['value']['#element_validate'] = array('_custom_form_validate_email');
    $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_node_submit';
  }
}

function custom_node_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'choose/your/path';
}
```

The code redirects the form independently from the button clicked to submit the form. If you want to redirect a form only when a specific submission button is clicked, then you should used the following code.

```
function custom_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#node']->type == 'custom') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Add Entry');
    $form['field_custom_email']['und'][0]['value']['#element_validate'] = array('_custom_form_validate_email');
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_node_submit';
  }
}

function custom_node_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'choose/your/path';
}
```

- The form ID doesn't contain hyphens. The form ID is the name of the PHP function that generates the form (a.k.a. the form builder), and a PHP function cannot contain hyphens in its name.
- The form ID is passed to the implementations of [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7), and [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` doesn't really need it, as it is called for a specific form, while the other two hooks are invoked for more than one form.
- The first function is the implementation of [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7); in this case, the base form ID is "node_form" that is the base form for the node edit form.
- The node edit form contains `$form['#node']`, which is the node object for the object being edited; "custom" is the short ID for the content type you want to redirect the users once they edit a node.
- Altering `$form_state['redirect']` from `hook_form_alter()` doesn't have any effect; it needs to be set from a submission handler.

Comment: Thanks for this. Note that the `&` in `function custom_node_submit($form, &$form_state) {` is very important. Otherwise you're not passing the state as a reference and the edits you manually do won't take affect.

Answer (score 9):

This code works on a Drupal 7 site.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */

function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {    
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mysubmit_node_submit';
  }     
}

function mysubmit_node_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = '/homepage';
}
```

Comment: Which answer are you referring as #4?

Comment: why is this not working for me? I am using the same code

Comment: Cleared your cache @ruby ?

Comment: For existing nodes, you better ensure to unset the destination first, which normally is added to the URL when you click the *edit* button on the `admin/content` page: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/192271/15055.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by setting `$form_state['redirect']`, for example using one of the following lines.

```
$form_state['redirect'] = "some-internal-path";
```

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array($path, $options_array, $http_code);
```

It's the same arguments you would pass to [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Shoaib Nawaz.  I added the $form_state['redirect'] to the hook_form_alter hook with out luck.

Comment: For the life of me, I cannot get $form_state['redirect'] to take effect anywhere.

Comment: This will *not* work if you try to redirect after a node has been added or edited. To see why, take a look at [node form submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/7.x). Whatever value you assign to `$form_state['redirect']` will be overwritten if `($node->nid)` evaluates to TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is an option for you, but if this is a content type you could achieve this pretty quickly by using the Rules module by setting a rule to be triggered on update or creation of a certain content type.