# Specifying a confirmation page after you signup using the Signup Module

Tags: 7, users

When using the Signup module, the form just reloads itself after every successful signup. Is it possible to redirect them to a different page instead of seeing the same page all over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a form then use `hook_form_alter` to add a submit handler with it and then define `$form['redirect']`. For illustration [see the post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6152/redirect-to-a-custom-page-after-a-node-has-been-added-or-edited)

Comment: That looks like a good post. Will check it out, thanks!