# Redirect after login from custom login block

Tags: 7, forms, users, redirection

I have added the login form to a page using `drupal_get_form`.
Now, I would like to redirect the users back to that page after login.
Note: I don't want to redirect users that logged in somewhere else (e.g. user/login), and I also don't want to use a contib module for that.

B.T.W
Maybe if I'll Ajaxify the login form it will have the same effect?

I'll appericiate any help and/or examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add form_alter and add custom #submit handler to user_login form if current_path() is correct for you and set `$form_state['redirect']` there.

Check this post [Redirect to a custom page after a node has been added or edited](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6152/redirect-to-a-custom-page-after-a-node-has-been-added-or-edited).

Also it can be achieved via custom rule, if you don't want to write any custom code.

Comment: It's not working because I'm using `drupal_get_form()` to get the form on my theme, and I don't want to use `hook_form_alter` because it will also redirect from the primary login form.

Comment: You can pass your own custom flag, for example `drupal_get_form($form_id, array('use_custom_redirect' => TRUE))` and then use this argument in form_alter - `if ($form_state['build_info']['args']['use_custom_redirect']) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You should save the current path and use that current path in the redirect path of the form

```
$redirect_url = current_path();
$form['#redirect'] = $redirect_url;
```