# Redirect a user after the node has been saved

Tags: hooks, forms

I'm looking for a hook to use after a node of a specific content type is created or saved, to perform a redirection to a specific page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of Drupal 6 [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) will help to perform on various actions, basing on the value of the first argument passed to the hook (`$op`).

- alter
- delete
- load
- update

In Drupal 7 there is a [number of hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7) for this.

- [hook_node_view_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7)
- [hook_node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7)
- [hook_node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7)
- [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7)

Answer (score 5):

[Form redirect after node save](http://www.brianvuyk.com/story-type/changing-redirect-value-drupal-node-form-d6).  This blog discusses the usually way of redirecting a form, the problem with node forms, and how to solve them for Drupal 6.   I believe it should also work for Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

For the completeness of this thread, [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/redirect-user-after-node-add-edit) is a link to a more detailed answer.
Either code it or add a rule using the [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Answer (score 0):

If "created" and "saved" mean node has been on database, here some option.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_NODE_TYPE_node_form_alter()
 * Add some action to submit button
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_NODE_TYPE_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'CUSTOM_MODULE_form_NODE_TYPE_node_form_submit';
}
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_NODE_TYPE_node_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
    $node = $form_state['node'];
    // CHECK NODE TYPE AND REDIRECT
}
```

[Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62698/accessing-nodeid-in-node-save-process/136584) similar case which can be done by this option.