# Accessing node#ID in node save process

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I just realized `hook_node_presave($node)` does not yet have a NODE#ID associated with the new node.

**Can anyone tell me if there is a hook in the node creating process where I can access the new nodes' nid?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hook_node_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) is the one you're looking for...

> This hook is invoked from node_save() after the database query that will insert the node into the node table is scheduled for execution, after the type-specific hook_insert() is invoked, and after field_attach_insert() is called.

Answer (score 0):

Some option by attaching function to submit button on node form.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_NODE_TYPE_node_form_alter()
 * Add some action to submit button
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_NODE_TYPE_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'CUSTOM_MODULE_form_NODE_TYPE_node_form_submit';
}
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_NODE_TYPE_node_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
    $node = $form_state['node'];
    // YOU CAN GET NID OR EVERYTHING THRUE $node
}
```