# Difference between create new and edit node in form alter

Tags: forms

I have an alter section for a particular content type. In the form alter how can I find out whether it is **create new form** or **edit form**?

With dsm($form) in from alter I can get results with several differences between them. What is the best way to distinguish those from each other?

is this a good way?

```
    if(isset($form['nid']['#value']))
     'means in edit form'
    else 
     'means in create new from'
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you look at the code of [node_object_prepare()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7), which is called from [node_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7) (the form builder for the node edit/create form), you will see it contains the following code.

```php
  // If this is a new node, fill in the default values.
  if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
    foreach (array('status', 'promote', 'sticky') as $key) {
      // Multistep node forms might have filled in something already.
      if (!isset($node->$key)) {
        $node->$key = (int) in_array($key, $node_options);
      }
    }
    global $user;
    $node->uid = $user->uid;
    $node->created = REQUEST_TIME;
  }
```

In an implementation of [`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7), it is enough to use code similar to the following one.

```php
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form_state['node'];

  if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
    // This is a new node.
  }
  else {
    // This is not a new node.
  }
}
```

If the node is new, then the form is creating a node; if the node is not new, then the form is editing an existing node.

In Drupal 8, every class implementing [`EntityInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/interface/EntityInterface/8.2.x) (including the [`Node`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/class/Node/8.2.x) class) override the [`EntityInterface::isNew()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3AisNew/8.2.x) method. Checking if a node is new becomes as easy as calling `$node->isNew()`. Since in Drupal 8 there isn't `$form_state['node']` anymore, the code becomes the following.

```php
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

  if ($node->isNew()) {
    // This is a new node.
  }
  else {
    // This is not a new node.
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are both conditions needed?

Comment: Because there could be a module that set the node ID for the new node, I guess.

Comment: better to use `!empty($node->is_new)` as `isset($node->is_new)` returns `TRUE` if it's set to `FALSE`.

Comment: @bloke_zero I take Drupal is not expecting it to be set to `FALSE`. Indeed, if there are some bad modules that set it to `FALSE` instead of unsetting it, it is better to accordly change the code.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you have to check if the node ID exists or not.

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#node'] && $form['#node']->type .'_node_form' === $form_id) {
    // Is node form.

    if ($form['#node']->nid) {
      // Is node edit form.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Drupal 8** you will need the `form_id` variable and it will be different on each case and it will include the `_edit_` in it if we are editing a node

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
    if($form_id == '"node_article_edit_form"'){
        //edit form
    }
    if($form_id == 'node_article_form') {
        //create form
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `->isNew()`, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223234/15055