# Prevent Field From Updating On Follow Up Saves?

Tags: rules

Use Case:

On *Page A* (Content Type A), there is a select list with options **A** and **B**

*1st Rule for Choice A*

User selects **A**, and a field "Date You Chose Letter" (a date field) captures the *current DateTime*.

*2nd Rule for Choice B*

User selects **B**, and the same field "Date You Chose Letter" (a date field) captures the *current DateTime*.

Easy enough.

But, when the User returns to *Page A*, makes some changes (and assume "A" is still selected) the 1st Rule triggers again, updating the "Date You Chose Letter" field with a new current Date/Time

The goal:  Do not update the "Date You Chose Letter" field after the initial selection. So I need to set in stone.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small custom module to lock down the original value of the field on edit, probably using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter would be the clearest way.

[Difference between create new and edit node in form alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34259/difference-between-create-new-and-edit-node-in-form-alter) provides a decent example, try that. Basically, you have to check in the $form object for an existing node. If it's an edit form, you have a node id already; if it's a new node, you don't.