# How to redirect the user to a specific page after node is added/edited by user

Tags: nodes, redirection, 7, files

I'm trying to create a drupal 7 website where users can upload pictures with a title.

When the user uploads an image with title, it has to be approved by the admin who then publishes it. My question is **after the user uploads the image**, how can I **redirect the user to a different page** which tells the user that the uploaded image has gone for approval by the admin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect user after node add/edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/redirect-user-after-node-add-edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to do that. If you haven't used it before you can take a look at [this video tutorial](https://drupalize.me/videos/overview-actions-conditions-and-events?p=1157).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the best way, I'm pretty new myself, but if the image was made as a content type it would be very easy to use revisioning workflow to the content type versus an image. Or to add a rule that when a new content type is created to execute that page or special messaging. Just a thought!